# Can i come back to a predefined viewstate of a page after coming back from another page?

Tags: c#, postback, viewstate

- What i've got is a Page1.aspx file, on this page i set some check boxes, some drop down values (a search filter page) that post back.
  The search page returns to me a list of records (based on what was selected in the search section of this page).
  Each record has a link to a "Details.aspx" page
- on Details.aspx page i am able to modify values of the record, once done, i would like to get back to Page1.aspx but have Page1.aspx page in the same state that i left it.
  By this i mean, i want the filters to be set as they were before the user navigated to the Details.aspx page

How can i do this?

i can not use history.back or history.go(-1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it: Put everything in a Session.

Load all the page1.aspx stuff into a class object, then add it to a Session (obviously before you go to the next page). Then when you go back check if that session exists, if it does, load the page using that class.

```
var myClass = new MyPage1Save 
{ 
    // load all the things you want saved
}

Session["Page1"] = myClass;
```